# How to jumble the elements in an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays

When an Double Integer is given and the digits of that integer are pushed into array. How to jumble these digits in the array?

Comment: `double` is not the same data type as  `Integer`. Can you give an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Answer (score 1):

> When an Double Integer is given

This statement is wrong , As @Mike Kobit mentioned , double is not same as integer , but for an Integer Array

## Try this

```
Integer i[]=new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5};
List<Integer> list=Arrays.asList(i);
System.out.println(list);  ------> Before Shuffling
Collections.shuffle(list);
System.out.println(list); -------> After shuffling
list.toArray(i);  -----> Convert list back to array
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -->Before Shuffling
[1, 3, 4, 2, 5] --> After Shuffling
```

Comment: if input is a number like Long. Is there a way to shuffle some digits? Eg: Input-->> 12897449879333 and output is -->>12897984349373

Comment: then create a Array of Long , I strongly suggest you to study [data Types in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)